# Spring value binding in @RequestMapping

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, controller, expression

I have a health check controller like the below one:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/${app-name}/management")
public class HealthCheckController {

    @GetMapping(path = "health", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public Mono<String> healthCheck() {
        return Mono.just("Ok");
    }
}
```

I have this controller in a common library and this library is included in all our services. In each service properties, I have given the value for `app-name`. So the URLs like `http://host:port/api/service1/management/health` will return `Ok`. This is working fine on my local machine but on the server, getting a 404 error. Our services are deployed in Kubernetes.

Am I missing anything here? Was the value binding in `@RequestMapping` (`${app-name}`) is correct usage?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637218/spring-boot-app-not-working-on-kubernetes-cluster Check this one

Comment: @rcvaram In the linked question, the pod restarts due to not ready. But we don't have any liveness probe yet. And other APIs are working fine, only this one is giving 404.